# Continuous function for absolute values of $x$

Tags: functions, continuity

For which values of $a, b$ is the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}ax + 5 &\text{for } |x|>2 \\(x-b)^2 &\text{for }|x|\leq 2\end{cases} $$

continuous on $\Bbb R$?

I know, that linear (the first case) and polynomial (the second case) are continuous. However, I don't know how to analyse their limits in $2$ if we have absolute value. Could you please explain the way if thinking, how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You are right that for $x \in (-2,2)$ (also written as $|x|<2$) the function is continuous and it also is for $x \in (-\infty,-2) \cup (2, \infty)$ (also written as $|x| > 2$). Now the question is what happens for $x = 2$ and $x = -2$ (written as $|x| = 2$).

You need that the "transition" from one function to another at both those points is "smooth", which can be expressed as
$$
\lim_{x \to -2^{-}} a x + 5
= \lim_{x \to 2^{+}} (x - b)^2
$$
and the same for $x = +2$.
Since both functions are continuous at those point the limits are just the values at those points and the above equation reduces to that
$$
ax + 5 = (x - b)^2
$$ 
must hold for $|x| = 2$.

Comment: Thus I solve this equation both for x = -2 and x=2, isn't it?

Comment: @Truename Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the function is continuous at $|x|=2$, so $x=\pm2$

At $x = 2$, we need 
$$\lim_{x\to2^-} ax+5 = \lim_{x\to 2^+} (x-b)^2$$
$$2a+5=(2-b)^2\tag{1}$$
At $x = -2$, we need 
$$\lim_{x\to-2^-} (x-b)^2 = \lim_{x\to -2^+} ax+5$$
$$(-2-b)^2=-2a+5\tag{2}$$
If we add $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$(2-b)^2+(-2-b)^2=10$$
This simplify to 
$$8+2b^2=10$$
$$b^2=1 \implies b=\pm1$$
Using each value of $b$ to find the corresponding value of $a$

Case $b=1$
$$2a+5=(2-1)^2 \implies a=-2$$
Case $b=-1$
$$2a+5=(2-(-1))^2 \implies a=2$$

There is two solutions, $(a=2, b=-1)$ and $(a=-2, b=1)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The function is continuous if

$
ax+5=(x-b)^2
$

for $|x|=2$ (i.e. $x=\pm 2$)

Comment: Thank you for nice formatting. However, is there any way to prove it using limits?

Comment: As you noted $ax+5$ is continuous so, for any $k$, we have that $lim_{x\to k}(ax+5)= ak+5$ and this is true for $|k|=2$

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your question is really about what does "for $|x|>2$" mean. If so, it means "for all values of $x$ where $|x|>2$". In other words for $x$-values in $(-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty)$. So you can rephrase it all without any absolute value bars and then maybe the confusion disappears?

Answer (score 0):

Check for both $x=+2$ and $x=-2$.